# I'm trying to drag and element using the mouse but it always starts dragging from a specific location and not the current location

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to drag a rectangle element called "Rec" using the mouse. I can drag it to the location I want and the rectangle stays there, but when I try to drag it again it returns to the first location and the dragging starts from there. I want to drag it from where I left it the last time. I just don't get where the problem is.

I have one Canvas only and all my elements are inside it, the Canvas is called the "maincanvas". I use the following very simple events to for dragging.

```
Point originalPosition = new Point(0, 0);
    private void Rec_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point CurrPosition = Mouse.GetPosition(MainCanvas);
        Canvas.SetLeft(e.Source as UIElement,  -( originalPosition.X - CurrPosition.X));
        Canvas.SetTop(e.Source as UIElement,  -(originalPosition.Y - CurrPosition.Y));

    }


    private void Rec_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement a = e.Source as UIElement;
        a.CaptureMouse();
        Rec.MouseMove += Rec_MouseMove;
        originalPosition = Mouse.GetPosition(MainCanvas);


    }

    private void Rec_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Rec.MouseMove -= Rec_MouseMove;
        UIElement a = e.Source as UIElement;
        a.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        originalPosition = new Point(0, 0);
    }
```

I hope you guys could help me.

Comment: You reset `originalPosition` to `(0,0)` after the mouse button has been released. I don't quite get the logic in your code snippet so I don't know if that is intended.

Comment: I wrote that part of the code by mistake because I wanted to try something, but it doesn't actually matter, because "originalPosition" will get a reset anyway when I start dragging again.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the mouse events on the Canvas like this:

```
<Canvas MouseLeftButtonDown="CanvasMouseLeftButtonDown"
        MouseLeftButtonUp="CanvasMouseLeftButtonUp"
        MouseMove="CanvasMouseMove">
   ...
</Canvas>
```

In the mouse down handler you would get the element that should be dragged by the MouseButtonEventArgs's `OriginalSource` property:

```
private UIElement draggedElement;
private Point lastMousePos;

private void CanvasMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource != sender)
    {
        IInputElement canvas = (IInputElement)sender;
        canvas.CaptureMouse();
        draggedElement = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;
        lastMousePos = e.GetPosition(canvas);
    }
}

private void CanvasMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ((IInputElement)sender).ReleaseMouseCapture();
    draggedElement = null;
}

private void CanvasMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (draggedElement != null)
    {
        var p = e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender);
        var dx = p.X - lastMousePos.X;
        var dy = p.Y - lastMousePos.Y;
        lastMousePos = p;

        Canvas.SetLeft(draggedElement, Canvas.GetLeft(draggedElement) + dx);
        Canvas.SetTop(draggedElement, Canvas.GetTop(draggedElement) + dy);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wrote your code but it didn't really work, nothing moved actually. Still, I don't get why I should handle these events on the Canvas when I can do it directly on the Rectangle. What's the difference ?

Comment: You probably did something wrong. The code works fine in my test application. Handling the events on the Canvas is simpler, because you attach handlers only once. Perhaps try the Preview versions of the events, like PreviewMouseMove. Also make sure the Left and Top properties of the child elements are initialized.